# Why I get TypeMismatch error in performing Pregel in Spark GraphX?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have wrote my algorithm with Pregel in Spark GraphX. But unfortunately I get TypeMismatch Error.
I load the graph with : `val my_graph= GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, path)`. So the beginning the nodes have a structure such as:

```
(1,1)
(2,1)
(3,1)
```

With nodeID as the key and 1 is its default property.

Inside the `run2` function, at first I change the structure in order to make a structure such that each node can store several properties. Because I'm working on overlapping community detection algorithm, so the properties are labels and their score.
At the first run of `run2`, each node has a structure such as:

```
(34,Map(34 -> (1.0,34)))
(13,Map(13 -> (1.0,13)))
(4,Map(4 -> (1.0,4)))
(16,Map(16 -> (1.0,16)))
(22,Map(22 -> (1.0,22)))
```

This means that node 34, has Label 34 and its score is equal to 1. Then each node can store several properties that receives from its neighbors and in the next steps it can send them to its neighbors.

At the end of the algorithm each node can contain several properties or just one property such as below structure:

```
(1,Map((2->(0.49,1),(8->(0.9,1)),(13->(0.79,1))))
(2,Map((11->(0.89,2)),(6->(0.68,2)),(13->(0.79,2)),(10->(0.57,2))))
(3,Map((20->(0.0.8,3)),(1->(0.66,3))))
```

The structure above shows that for example, node 1 belongs to community 2 with score 0.49, and belongs community 8 with score 0.9 and belongs to community 13 with score 0.79.

The below code shows the different functions defined in Pregel.

```
def run2[VD, ED: ClassTag](graph: Graph[VD, ED], maxSteps: Int) = {

  val temp_graph = graph.mapVertices { case (vid, _) => mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)](vid -> (1,vid)) }

  def sendMessage(e: EdgeTriplet[mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)], ED]): Iterator[(VertexId, mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double, VertexId)])] = {
    Iterator((e.srcId,e.dstAttr), (e.dstId,e.srcAttr))
  }

  def mergeMessage(count1: (mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)]), count2: (mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)]))= {

    val communityMap = new mutable.HashMap[VertexId, List[(Double, VertexId)]]

    (count1.keySet ++ count2.keySet).map(key => {

      val count1Val = count1.getOrElse(key, (0D,0:VertexId))
      val count2Val = count2.getOrElse(key, (0D,0:VertexId))

      communityMap += key->(count1Val::communityMap(key))
      communityMap += key->(count2Val::communityMap(key))

    })
    communityMap
  }

  def vertexProgram(vid: VertexId, attr: mutable.HashMap[VertexId,(Double, VertexId)], message: mutable.HashMap[VertexId, List[(Double, VertexId)]]) = {
    if (message.isEmpty)
      attr
    else {
      val labels_score: mutable.HashMap[VertexId, Double] = message.map {
        key =>
          var value_sum = 0D
          var isMemberFlag = 0
          var maxSimilar_result = 0D
          val max_similar = most_similar.filter(x=>x._1==vid)(1)
          if (key._2.exists(x=>x._2==max_similar)) isMemberFlag = 1 else isMemberFlag = 0

          key._2.map {
            values =>
              if (values._2==max_similar) maxSimilar_result = values._1 else maxSimilar_result = 0D

              val temp = broadcastVariable.value(vid)(values._2)._2
              value_sum += values._1 * temp
          }
          value_sum += (beta*value_sum)+((1-beta)*maxSimilar_result)
          (key._1,value_sum) //label list
      }


      val max_value = labels_score.maxBy(x=>x._2)._2.toDouble
      val dividedByMax = labels_score.map(x=>(x._1,x._2/max_value)) // divide by maximum value

      val resultMap: mutable.HashMap[VertexId,Double] = new mutable.HashMap[VertexId, Double]
      dividedByMax.foreach{ row => // select labels more than threshold P = 0.5
        if (row._2 >= p) resultMap += row
      }

      val max_for_normalize= resultMap.values.sum
      val res = resultMap.map(x=>(x._1->(x._2/max_for_normalize,x._1))) // Normalize labels

      res
    }
  }

  val initialMessage = mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)]()

  val overlapCommunitiesGraph = Pregel(temp_graph, initialMessage, maxIterations = maxSteps)(
    vprog = vertexProgram,
    sendMsg = sendMessage,
    mergeMsg = mergeMessage)

  overlapCommunitiesGraph
}

val my_graph= GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, path)
val new_updated_graph2 = run2(my_graph, 1)
```

In the above code, `p=0.5` and `beta=0.5`. `most_similar` is an RDD that contains each node and its most important node. For example `(1,3)` means that node 3 is the most similar neighbor to node 1. The `broadcatVariable` structure is the same as below:

```
(19,Map(33 -> (1.399158675718661,0.6335049099178383), 34 -> (1.4267350687130098,0.6427405501408145)))

(15,Map(33 -> (1.399158675718661,0.6335049099178383), 34 -> (1.4267350687130098,0.6427405501408145)))
...
```

The structure shows relationships between a node as key and its neighbors as value. For example, node 19 is neighbor with node 33 and 34, and the relationship is shown by the score between them.

In the algorithm each node sends each property which is `Map` containing several labels and their score. Then in the `mergeMessage` function, the value of the labels with same number are put into a `List` and in the `vertexProgram` for each label or key, its list is processed.

**Updated**

According to the equation in below picture I use a `List` to gather different scores for a Label and process them in the `vertexProgram` function. Because I need `P_ji` for processing each nodes' label score, so I don't know if is it possible to perform it in the `mergeMessage` function or if it needs to be in `vertexProgram`. `P_ji` is a score between source node and its neighbors which should be multiplied to the label score.

[image]

The error that I get is shown in front of the line `vprog = vertexProgram,` and is shown in this picture. Can anyone please help me by solving this error?

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code for creating the graph and the values for all required variables (otherwise it's not possible to run). Currently missing values for `most_similar`, `p`, `beta`, `broadcastVariable`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have Edited the question's text and explained every necessary things. if you can help me this, i would be so thankful. because this problem has taken several days and i am confused with it.

Comment: I think the problem is due to the mix of `HashMap[VertexId, List[(Double, VertexId)]]` and `HashMap[VertexId, (Double, VertexId)]`. Especially, `mergeMessage` which takes `HashMap` without list as input and returns a `HashMap` with a list in the output. The input and output types needs to be the same here, otherwise a merged message can't merge again.

Comment: thank you for your help. Sorry i ask, but is it possible to guide me that which part of the code i can change to solve this? I mean should change the nodes property or which part should i change. i am really confused

Comment: The easiest way should be to not use a list but if that is possible depends on the actual logic. Is there any way to write the `mergeMessage` without where the output is a `HashMap[VertexId, (Double, VertexId)]`?

Comment: It would be good idea to not to use List. But for implementing this part of the algorithm only using List comes to my mind. i want to make a structure that looks like this: ```Map((1->List((0.3,5),(0.8,7),(0.02,10), ...)))```. this means that community or group 1 consists of nodes 5,7 and 10. I can't think of other way. if there is easier way for doing this i would be so happy to know.

Comment: is it possible to use ```mutable.Hashmap``` and add new values to previous values for a Key? for example, we have ```(1->(0.5,5))``` and is it possible to add (0.36,8) to key 1 and make the structure: ```(1->((0.5,5),(0.36,8))```? is it true or it is not possible?

Comment: That's not possible. Would computing `labels_score` (where the messages are used) in an iterative way work? I.e., 2 messages at a time inside the `mergeMessage` function.

Comment: I am not sure, but is it possible to know the current nodes's ID in merge message? we should use the relationship between the sourceId and its neighbors. if we know the current node's ID, we can perform ```labels_score``` in merge step but i think we do not have access to the node ID (i mean the vid that is defined in vertex program function). is it right or we can access to the ```vid(vertexId of current node)``` ?

Comment: I added **Updated** part to the question which shows what i want to compute

Comment: I added an answer below with sketches on solutions for both options. You can see if any of them matches what you want. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you use two different types for the messages. The initial messages are of type `mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)]` but after merging two (with the `mergeMessage` function) the type becomes `mutable.HashMap[VertexId, List[(Double,VertexId)]]`. The problem here is that now the merged message can't merge with another message since the type is wrong.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Change the message type to `mutable.HashMap[VertexId, List[(Double,VertexId)]]`, making sure the initial messages matches this.
2. Keep the message type as `mutable.HashMap[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)]` and change the output type of `mergeMessage` to match.

Below are some sketches on possible solutions for both options. There could be some errors inside them since the actual wanted logic is not very clear (there are some unused variables in the code, etc.) Both options can run when combined with the rest of the code and will return a new graph.

---

**Solution 1**:

You need to adjust `sendMessage`, `mergeMessage` and `initialMessage` to handle Lists. This could be done as follows:

```
def sendMessage(e: EdgeTriplet[Map[VertexId, (Double,VertexId)], ED]): Iterator[(VertexId, Map[VertexId, List[(Double, VertexId)]])] = {
  val msg1 = e.dstAttr.map{ case (k,v) => (k, List(v)) }
  val msg2 = e.srcAttr.map{ case (k,v) => (k, List(v)) }
  Iterator((e.srcId, msg1), (e.dstId, msg2))
}

def mergeMessage(count1: Map[VertexId, List[(Double,VertexId)]], count2: Map[VertexId, List[(Double,VertexId)]])= {
  val merged = count1.toSeq ++ count2.toSeq
  val new_message = merged.groupBy(_._1).map{case (k,v) => (k, v.map(_._2).flatten.toList)}
  new_message
}

val initialMessage = Map[VertexId, List[(Double,VertexId)]]()
```

Possibly the `messages.isEmpty` return in `vertexProgram` needs to be adjusted as well.

**Solution 2**:

To use a message without the a list, you need to move the merging logic from `vertexProgram` to `mergeMessage`. I simplified the code somewhat so the code could require some testing.

```
def mergeMessage(count1: (Map[VertexId, (Double, VertexId)]), count2: (Map[VertexId, (Double, VertexId)]))= {

  val merged = count1.toSeq ++ count2.toSeq
  val grouped = merged.groupBy(_._1)

  val new_message = grouped.map{ case (key, key_values) =>
    val values = key_values.map(_._2)
    
    val max_similar = most_similar.filter(x => x._1 == key).headOption match {
      case Some(x) => x  
      case _ => -1   // What should happen when there is no match?
    }
  
    val maxSimilar_result = values.filter(v => v._2 == max_similar).headOption match {
      case Some(x) => x._1
      case _ => 0.0
    }
    
    val value_sum = values.map{ v => v._1 * broadcastVariable.value(key)(v._2)._2}.sum
    val res = (beta*value_sum)+((1-beta)*maxSimilar_result)
    (key, (res, key))
  }
  
  new_message.toMap
}

def vertexProgram(vid: VertexId, attr: Map[VertexId, (Double, VertexId)], messages: Map[VertexId, (Double, VertexId)]) = {
  if (messages.isEmpty){
    attr
  } else { 
    val labels_score = messages.map(m => (m._1, m._2._1))
    val max_value = labels_score.maxBy(x => x._2)._2.toDouble
    val dividedByMax = labels_score.map(x => (x._1, x._2 / max_value)) // divide by maximum value

    // select labels more than threshold P = 0.5
    val resultMap = dividedByMax.filter{ row => row._2 >= p }

    val max_for_normalize= resultMap.values.sum
    val res = resultMap.map(x => (x._1 -> (x._2 / max_for_normalize, x._1))) // Normalize labels

    res
  }
}
```

**Notes**:

1. Currently in `sendMessage`, a message is sent to both nodes independent of the direction of the graph edges. If this is correct depends on the wanted logic.
2. I changed `mutable.HashMap` to a normal (immutable) `Map`. It's always preferred to use the immutable option if possible.
3. Solution 1 should be simpler to use as the logic in `vertexProgram` is quite complicated. There are some more variables there that did not do anything currently but maybe they will be used later. If it's not possible to merge messages in an iterative fashion (and you need to look at all messages at once) then using a `List` would be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It didn't exactly solve the problem, but the code helped me a lot in logic and solving errors. thank you

Comment: I solved my problem with syntax errors but when i execute i get error of key not found. i posted my problem in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63428029/how-to-handle-error-of-key-not-found-in-spark) . if you mind please check it. thank you

Comment: @hamid: Happy to help :). I think the error should be due to difference in input (`most_similar` or `broadcastVariable`). I will take a look at the new question.